# Brand new to Java, need some help restarting a while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, calculator

I have just started learning Java in the last week or so and I'm creating a program that acts as a sales calculator that calculates commission. 
My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {

int itemOne;
int itemTwo;
int itemThree;
int itemFour;

final double baseCommission = 200;

final double itemOnePrice = 239.99;
final double itemTwoPrice = 129.75;
final double itemThreePrice = 99.95;
final double itemFourPrice = 350.89;


final double commissionPercentage = 0.09;

boolean startLoop = false;

public void start(){

    while (startLoop = false);
    {
        //Welcome message
        System.out.println("Welcome to Devon's Sales Calculator!");

        //Defining new scanner
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Getting user input for salesperson name along with number of items sold as well as assigning them to a variable
        String salesman_name;
        System.out.print("Insert salesperson name:\t");
        salesman_name = user_input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter number of first item sold:\t");
        int first_item = user_input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter number of second item sold:\t");
        int second_item = user_input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter number of third item sold:\t");
        int third_item = user_input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter number of fourth item sold:\t");
        int fourth_item = user_input.nextInt();


        //Printing out the name of the salesmen, followed by the total price of items sold
        System.out.println("Sales Person\t" + salesman_name);

        System.out.println("Total price of first item sold\t" + first_item * itemOnePrice);

        System.out.println("Total price of second item sold\t" + second_item * itemTwoPrice);

        System.out.println("Total price of third item sold\t" + third_item * itemThreePrice);

        System.out.println("Total price of fourth item sold\t" + fourth_item * itemFourPrice);

        //Calculating total of all items sold
        double finalPrice = first_item * itemOnePrice + second_item * itemTwoPrice + third_item * itemThreePrice + fourth_item * itemFourPrice;

        //Calculating commission @ 0,9%
        System.out.println("Total commission earned\t" + finalPrice * commissionPercentage);

        //Decision whether or not to restart the while loop 
        String decision;
        System.out.println("Would you like to check another salesperson?");
        decision = user_input.next();

        if(decision == "yes"){
            startLoop = false;
        }

        else if(decision == "no"){
            startLoop = true;
            }

        }

     }
}
```

Whenever I execute my while loop, it doesn't restart to choose another salesman. I'm probably doing something horribly wrong and my code formatting is probably horrible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've deleted your javascript tag since this question isn't about this completely different language, and you don't want to mislead the Javascript experts, and have the wrong folks reviewing your question.

Comment: Get rid of the = false and the semicolon! `while (startLoop = false);` Change it to `while (!startLoop)`

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic since it's really just about a typographical error.

Comment: Use an array for your 4 items and prices so you don't have to repeat yourself over and over again.

Comment: @D. Leigh don't use == to compare Strings, use equals() instead. Or better, equalsIgnoreCase().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the = false and the semicolon. So not:

```
while (startLoop = false);
{
   System.out.println("foo");
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
while (startLoop = false) {
    // do nothing
}

{
   System.out.println("foo");
}
```

Instead do,

```
while (!startLoop) {
    // do something here
}
```